# Unity IOC configuration with json

Tags: c#, unity-container

In the `app.config`, it can look like below and the services and repositories are defined in a different file `Unity.config`. My question is, is it possible to do below in `appsettings.json` instead of `app.config` and `Unity.json` instead of `Unity.config`?

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="Unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" requirePermission="false" restartOnExternalChanges="true" />
    </configSections>
    <Unity configSource="Config\Unity.config"/>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="DateFormat" value="yyyyMMdd"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Unity.config**

```
<Unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="IHelpfulRepository" type="Repositories.IHelpfulRepository, Repositories" />
    <alias alias="HelpfulRepository" type="Repositories.Implementation.HelpfulRepository, Repositories" />
</Unity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no it's not possible. there is a work around.

So what I had to do was make my own UnityContainerExtensions class, load an xml file that looks just like an app.config file, get the unity section, and convert that to a UnityConfigurationSection. code below

**MyUnityContainerExtensions.cs**

```
public static class MyUnityContainerExtensions
{
    public static IUnityContainer LoadXML(this IUnityContainer container, string xmlFilePath = ".\\Config\\Unity.config")
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlFilePath);
        var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = xmlFilePath };
        Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)configuration.GetSection("unity");
        return section.Configure(container, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

**Unity.config**

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="Unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Unity.Configuration" requirePermission="false" restartOnExternalChanges="true" />
    </configSections>
    <Unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
        <alias alias="IHelpfulRepository" type="Repositories.IHelpfulRepository, Repositories" />
        <alias alias="HelpfulRepository" type="Repositories.Implementation.HelpfulRepository, Repositories" />
    </Unity>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Then where I'm loading the unity configuration, I just call the new extension method.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer().LoadXML();
```